# how to get all the cells height in tableview when the cells are of different height?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swift4

I found option to get visible cell height as shown in below but how to get all the cell height

```
     let cells = self.tableView.visibleCells
    for cell in cells {
        heightOfTableView += cell.frame.height
    }
```

Comment: Check cell.tableview.contentsize

Comment: Use min(tableview.contentsize, tableView.frame.height) .

Comment: What are you meaning when you are saying all cell? all which are visible on the table view or items count which should draw when scrolling?

Comment: @karthikeyan worked

Comment: Check cell.tableview.contentsize.height

Comment: @sivakumar nice to hear.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. UITableView only keeps the visible cells around. As soon they scroll out of the visible area they are discarded.

What you might want instead is the `contentSize.height` inherited from `UIScrollView`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this whichever cell height is fixed for returning constant value and for variable height use `AutomaticDimension`.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    if indexPath.row == 0{
        return 160
    }else{
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.row == 0{
        return 160
    }else{
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
}
```

Comment: Read question again, this is not related to that question